# Html form with multiple tabs- Data submission

Tags: html, jsp

[image]Team,

I have a html form with multiple tabs. I have only one submit button which submit all data .Whats the best way to do this?. Also if i switch between tabs values maintained but not submitted and saved will they be retained?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple tabs? Depending on what you use, the values are kept or not between changes. This is why you are asked to submit some [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code when asking questions.

Comment: I told  A html form with multiple tabs...I dont understand  whats is the confusion  regarding this. As per my understanding that description is clear and there are no 100 ways to create  a form with multiple tabs inside... Regarding code..I have not started coding still on conceptual phase only hence queried.. I was  visualizing some thing as  shown in image...Reg image

Comment: There are many ways of creating tabs. You can obviously make a dynamic app module that hides the rest of the inputs until you conplete the previous tab. You can load the next inputs if some field has some value. You really have an universe if possibilities. You'll see when you'll start coding. Even a low-level mockup will change your pov. As to ask to your question, values not submitted will not be generally retained.